# Checkbox checked only one from the grouup on click over div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need to check checkbox on click over the div where checkbox resides inside that div. Now I need to check only one checkbox from the category.
My code is working fine but its only work with checkbox change event not on div click.

```
<script>
$(':checkbox').on('change',
    function () {
        var th = $(this), id = th.prop('id');
        if (th.is(':checked')) {
            $(':checkbox[id="' + id + '"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
            //console.log("a")
        }
    });
```

Comment: Something seems wrong here? Your `id` variable has the ID of the current element, yet you're selecting all checkboxes with the same ID, except the current one, which means there's more than one element with the same ID?

Comment: Yes there are more than one element with same `id`, I need to check only one of them at the same time, above code is working fine, but I need this one on the click over `<div>` tag.

Comment: "*its only work with checkbox change event not on div click*". Because you `$(':checkbox').on('change',` and not `$('#yourDiv').on('click'`?

Comment: @RahibMemon You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. All the code that deals with IDs expects them to be unique.

Comment: and share your html and create a jsfiddle if possible. It'll be easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @adiga Don't tell people to create jsfiddle, tell them to create Stack Snippet.

Comment: @Barmar will do

Comment: @Barmar its simple I have a view in which I am having the multiple options within few same categories, now my concern is to check the checkbox on div click event but it should select only one checkbox from the each category... the concern is that the above code is working fine on checkbox click even not on div.

Comment: If you can only check one checkbox from a category, why don't you use radio buttons?

Comment: And if you want clicking on the text to be treated like clicking on the checkbox, use `<label>` instead of `<div>`.